# 2008 R2 Clients not Updating their time from the Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, time

I have set the time on the primary domain controller emulator but my clients don't seem to be adjusting there time.

- The other domain controller did sync its time to the main controller
- The domain controllers are VMs but the clients that should be syncing with them are not
- The "Type" of the clients from `w32tm /dumpreg /subkey:parameters` is NT5DS
- I don't see any errors in the event logs
- I set the time about 6 hours ago and the clients are still 4 minutes off
- A manual `w32tm /resync` gets a client to update its time, but that is not really a solution

**Update:**
I did a domain rename and renamed the dcs as well to corepsond.  `w32tm /query /peers /verbose` shows the peer is still the old DC.  Any know how I teach the clients about the new one?

Answer (score 5):

Is your PDC Emulator getting a good external-to-the-forest time sync? If your PDC Emulator doesn't have an authoritative time source configured I don't believe clients will sync. You can see more details at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042

You may want to run a `w32tm /resync` on one of the machines and see if the clock syncs. That's quick-and-dirty, but it'll tell you if a sync is even possible.

Have a look at the output of `w32tm /query /peers /verbose`. That'll show you what the client's peer selection algorithm is coming up with.

Is anything blocking UDP port 123 traffic between the clients and their domain controllers?

Answer (score 2):

To configure a client computer for automatic domain time synchronization
Open a Command Prompt.

Type the following command and then press ENTER:

`w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update`

Type the following command and then press ENTER:

`net stop w32time`

Type the following command and then press ENTER:

`net start w32time`

[source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758905(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: That should just set the "Nt5DS" setting in the "Type" parameter of the W32Time configuration, which Kyle says is already set. (Having said that, I haven't come up w/ any ideas re: why the clients are still asking for the old DC name, though...)

Comment: Try:w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:<external ntp server> /update; then net stop w32time && net start w32time; then run the commands above?